# What is the simplest way to obtain my ethereum public key, provided that i have the private key?

Tags: wallets, web3.py, private-key, cryptography, public-key

I have been looking for an easy way to get the public key of my ethereum wallet

From reading a bit on how ethereum wallets work, I understand that a **Wallet Address** in ethereum is actually derived from the public key (an address is the last 20 bytes of a keccak-256 hash of the public key), but it is in fact NOT the public key itself

therefore my question,

**"What is the simplest way to get my ethereum public key, provided i know my private key"**

any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out !

thanks to [Timur's article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-an-ethereum-wallet-address-from-a-private-key-ae72b0eee27b/) and also the [ecies](https://github.com/ecies/py) and [ecdsa](https://github.com/tlsfuzzer/python-ecdsa) libraries

here's the python code sample

```
from ecies.utils import generate_eth_key, generate_key
from ecies import encrypt, decrypt
import codecs
import ecdsa

private_key = 'abcd1234' # your ethereum private key

pr_key_bytes = codecs.decode(private_key,'hex')

pb_key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(pr_key_bytes,curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).verifying_key

pb_key_bytes = pb_key.to_string()

privK = private_key

pubK = pb_key_bytes.hex()

# to prove that we found the correct public key, which corresponds to the aforesaid private key

data = b'abc' # convert the data to byte form, since the encrypt function only accepts byte encoded data as a parameter

enc = encrypt(pubK, data)

decrypt(privK, enc) # decrypting with private key should give b'abc' as answer
```